# Spinner не показывает hint при смене конфигурации

Tags: android, android-spinner

Товарищи, выручайте! Уже несколько дней подряд сижу над (вроде простецкой штукой) как spinner. На спиннер я поставила hint вот таким способом:

```
private void createAndSetSpinnerAdapter() {
    if (isAdded()) {
        // Set hint for spinner
        mSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) {
            @Override
            @NonNull
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                if (position == getCount()) {
                    ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                    ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount()));
                }
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return super.getCount() - 1;
            }
        };
        mSpinnerAdapter.addAll(mListOfAllCategories);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
        mSpinner.setSelection(mSpinnerAdapter.getCount());
    }
}
```

В методе onCreateView() фрагмента я прослушиваю загрузились ли данные из БД (работаю с Realm). И там же создаю список данных для адаптера и вызываю метод createAndSetSpinnerAdapter():

```
// Work with spinner
    mQuoteCategoryList.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<QuoteCategory>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<QuoteCategory> element) {
            //Создаем список категорий для спиннера
            //Hint является последним элементом в списке
            createQuoteCategoryListForSpinner(element);
            //Set spinner selection on current category
            /** Тут еще ряд проверка на текущие выбранные значения, 
                но они тут опущены для простоты*/
                createSpinnerAdapter();     
                //createSpinnerAdapter();              
                }
    });
```

Так вот при первой загрузке hint отображается и все идет отлично. При повороте экрана hint не появляется и...это плохо.(Забавная случайность: если вызвать два раза настройку спиннера (закомментированный метод), то все работает на ура, но это конченый идиотизм и я не пойму почему этот идиотизм работает) По логам мы не проходим условие if (position == getCount()) {...} почему я просто без понятия. И да, почему-то студия предупреждает о том, что много всего выполняется в главном потоке. Хотя убираю спиннер и никаких проблем. Весь косяк именно в нем. Я реально в агонии уже от этого спиннера...помогите кто чем может, с меня шоколадка, да сколько угодно шоколадок, только бы понять в чем дело!

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что сам адаптер немного асинхронно назначается... Попробуйте как-то так: `mSpinner.post(new Runnable(){public void run(){mSpinner.setSelection(mSpinnerAdapter.getCount());}});`

Comment: этот алгоритм с хинтом через адаптер и getCount() не работает при смене ориентации и мне тоже не удалось разобраться, почему. В итоге использовал библиотеку, [Material Better Sppiner](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1707), но есть  много аналогичных (с хинтом) на github. Realm имеет [свой адаптер](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters), который работает непосредственно с выборкой из БД, зачем нужно использовать какой то ArrayAdapter и терять время и ресурсы на бесполезную перегонку данных

Comment: @pavlofff, со сменой ориентации дело пошло на лад. Только вот загвоздка стала в следующих вещах: 1. На спиннер надо нажимать два раза, чтобы его открыть; 2. Если программно добавить в список спиннера еще элемент он не становится текущим (я в диалоге создаю новый элемент). Вы не сталкивались с таким? (весь код во фрагменте)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, тоже об этом думала, вытаскивала из слушателя, но безуспешно. Исход тот же...

Comment: Прошлась по всем популярным библиотекам по спиннеру и везде какой-то косяк...пока оставлю свою реализацию. Кстати, насчет кастомного адаптера для спиннера: мы же кастомный адаптер наследуем от RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<T, V>, а нам надо для спиннера унаследоваться от ArrayAdapter, иначе просто этот адаптер не подходит. Если обычный список заполнить, то все работает отлично, а если спиннер, то приходится извлекать значения заранее. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: спиннер, как и любой другой виджет-список работает с любым типом адаптера. ArrayAdapter не обладает никакой исключительной силой спиннера. Вообще смысл любого адаптера. состоит в том, чтобы отдать виджету-списку данные в понятном ему формате и не важно, какие данные при этом на входе в адаптер. Какие проблемы с BetterSpinner? он построен вообще на основе EditText  и работает с хинтом "из коробки", через атрибуты виджета, а не адаптер. Никаких проблем при повороте нет, так же у виджета отличная кастомизируемость (смотрите документацию). Если вы нашли какое то решение, оформите его как ответ.

Comment: при добавлении в спиннер, добавленный элемент и не должен стать выбранным, с чего бы ему таким быть (по умолчанию выбирается первый элемент списка, програмно можно назначить любой через `setSelection()`)

Comment: Решение не найдено, так как исправив смену ориентации всплывают другие ошибки - это не решение. В предложенной Вами библиотеке есть (для моего случая) ряд проблем. 1. Это требование двойного щелчка (никакие фокусаблы не исправляют это); 2. Пользователь выбирая в спиннере "создать новую категорию", во всплывающем диалоге вводит новое название, которое при нажатии ОК диалога автоматические должно устанавливаться - это весьма логично, неправда ли. Заставлять пользователя ещё раз открывать список и выбирать введённую категорию не самое разумное решение.

Comment: 3. setSelection(...) в этой библиотеки не работает. Народ использует в ней setText(), но фишка в том, что в Активити может это работать, а во фрагменте нет (в ишью разработчики делились этими мыслями). И если во фрагменте вызвать последний метод, то он установит новой значение как текущее в спиннер, но удалит другие. Так что это явно не решение. Итог: данная библиотека (и ряд других просмотренных) не подходит в моем случае. Так что код остаётся пока "костыльным".